Hide sensitive key
I have this properties in my properties.yml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: mydb_link_cloud
    username: ${RDS_USERNAME}
    password: ${RDS_PASSWORD}

I already know how to save these sensitive key in my local environment in inteleJ.
But how to store them in beanstalk where i'm deploying my server.
How to store sensitive in cloud server

Get an AWS Secrets Manager secret in an AWS CloudFormation resource - AWS Secrets Manager
